# Sorry, the application add-apt-repository has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: crash, add-apt-repository

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm getting a crash report as soon as i log in. This is what the report looks like:

[image]

I have no idea about what to do with that.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being voted down, it has a lot of information, and is a fair way to ask the question.  I too get this message, and this is one of the very few answers to come up when asking about "Sorry, the application add-apt-repository has stopped unexpectedly."  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case the error was caused by having an incorrect package repository specified. With help of Synaptic package manager you can find out which one is the problem: press Reload in Synaptic and wait for warnings. Then go to Settings - Repositories and disable the troublesome repository. Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks Arjan, this worked for me too (15.04, the same crash report).